# Why NavigationView should be placed at last in XML Layout file?

Tags: android, androidx

I am developing an Android Application in which I have a NavigationView. Along with the `NavigationView` my Layout file consists of a LinearLayout. In order to make the menu items of the NavigationView clickable, I implemented the `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` interface in my activity. However, after clicking the item, the method `onNavigationItemSelected` didn't get called. Later I found out that by **placing the NavigationView at the end**, the whole thing works as expected. Can anyone explain this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the DrawerLayout's [`onInterceptTouchEvent`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:drawerlayout/drawerlayout/src/main/java/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout.java;l=1536) method, you'll see this being executed on an `ACTION_DOWN` event:

```
final View child = mLeftDragger.findTopChildUnder((int) x, (int) y);
if (child != null && isContentView(child)) {
    interceptForTap = true;
}
```

And that will cause `onInterceptTouchEvent` to return `true`, which will cause click event will be stealed from child views and called on the `DrawerLayout` instead.

`ViewDragHelper.findTopChildUnder` just scans the children in reversed order so it finds the content view first because you placed it last.